# Google Play Store: App page does not show download statistics

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

I have developed few apps, and **published them on google playstore**, but it is ***not showing number of installs to user***.

What's wrong in that, can you help me in that?
Look at this screenshot to understand my problem,there is no additional information shown for number of installs

[image]

My apps can be seen [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Tocus%20App).

*By the way is google analytics code neccessary to show it?

I didn't implemented analytics code in my app.*

Comment: it will take some more time to show number of installs to user.when you upadate your apk on playstore?

Comment: I have updated my apk before 3 days. @sasikumar

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it not about **programming**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is not showing number of installs to user.

For new apps it takes around 1.5 to 2 days before the first set of download statistics show up. (if there are downloads during that period). Ratings on the other hand reflect immediately.

Also, If you see in on your developer console and not on your play store app: clear cache for the playstore app and restart the play store app. It will show up.

> By the way does google analytics code neccessary to show it ? i didn't
>   implemented analytic code in my app.

No, implementing analytics in your app is not necessary. But, it is recommended if you want to have more accurate and sometimes real time overviews of your app details.

Comment: i have published my 1st app on 2nd January, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.tocus.makarsankrantiphotoframe @Virus

Comment: Do the statistics show on developer console? Once it shows there users will also see it on the play store app

Comment: No, statistics  also not show on developer console. @virus

Comment: Relax it will show up in a day or two. Statics update on play store is really weird, unpredictable and inaccurate. You'll get comfortable with it soon. :)

Comment: Thanks, I will wait for more time, if statics appear then i will mark your answer as right. @Virus

Comment: I could see the download statistics for your apps when i checked now.

Comment: Yes, finally my app show statistic about apps, your answer is appreciated. @Virus