# App installs not listing in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api

I recently published my app on the app store two days ago, yesterday some one else and I downloaded my app in our devices. The console still has not updated with any installations especially since I know of a couple more installs that happened today. What should I do?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605544/google-play-store-app-page-does-not-show-download-statistics/34605593#34605593

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only does Play take a long time to update that control panel, it's not going to show you exactly what you expect.  So, for a start, it could be at least 24 hours behind.

In addition to this, you could install the app on 5 devices yourself, and only ONE will show up in Play.  This is because they are all from the same IP address.  I've run into this where I was working as a freelancer to download/test an app.  I couldn't get credit for unique installs unless I was on completely different networks for each install.

Comment: I understand the whole ip address thing what I don't understand is that I uploaded the app two days ago and got at least one download yesterday. I guess I'll wait.

Comment: I also have another question, my app is a unit conversion app called Converjz, it is under the tools category and in the description clearly states that it is a unit conversion app in the first sentence,  but when I search for unit conversion, I cannot find the app and when I click on similarities on my app page it comes up with no results.

Comment: That's another thing that takes time to propagate over Google's database/network/index.  If a week goes by and you still don't see anything, you might have a problem.

Comment: Ok thanks one more thing, I know u have to wait until the app is added to its similarities but I read something I'm android tutorials that I have to link my app to search results, should I do that and how do I do it?

Comment: Google will do this sort of thing on its own.  Just follow the tips and guidelines for what sorts of words you should have in your description.  Then, you can use a paid service like AdWords, to get your app ranked higher in search results.

Comment: Ok Google is just slow with doing that because I'm still not in the similar app listings hopefully soon I did contact their developing team, hoping to hear back soon. Thanks for all your help!